# Creating object of non pointer type in C++

Tags: c++

If i have a class like as below.

```
class A {
int data;
};

A a; // Case1: calling explicit Default constructor
A b(); // Case2: Calling implicit default constructor
```

What is the difference between Case1 and Case2?

Answer (score 9):

```
A b();
```

it does not define an object, it declares a function which returns type `A`, It's also well known as [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: +1; knew it had a technical name

Answer (score 2):

```
A b(); // Case2: Calling implicit default constructor
```

The comment is **incorrect**. `A b();` is a function declaration (The function is called `b` and returns an object of type `A` and you intend to *define* the function later) **not** an object definition.

Comment: It isn't incorrect. It's just not what he thought it was.

Comment: @EJP: the comment is wrong. Incorrect comments are worse than no comments. I've amended my answer.

Comment: Agreed, but that isn't what you said originally, i.e. what I commented on.

Comment: @EJP: Indeed. The line as a whole has incorrectness in it though. Still, due to the excellence of the other answer, I'll probably remove this one: it adds nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

```
    A a; // Case1: calling explicit Default constructor
```

Calls the implicit default constructor, since you hadn't provided one in the class.

Case 2:

```
   A b(); // Case2: Calling implicit default constructor
```

It is the function decleration say "b" is the function name and it takes no argument and returns A object.

Hope it helps.